# Get latitude longitude when blue dot moves on google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

I want to get latitude and longitude value when blue dart moves on android google map.
Basically, I want to get current location of the phone with high accuracy and immediate update on location change.

But LocationListener not frequently called method onLocationChanged(), that's why I am not getting latest location value.

I tried lot's of other possibilities to get a location with high accuracy and frequently updated value.

I searched and found Fused Location API which is deprecated.

I did not find any website where they solve the issue to get frequent and latest location value.

If I will get blue dart location value then I think my problem will get resolved.

[image]

Code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady() method called");
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    if (checkPermission())
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);

    View locationButton = ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).
            getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();

    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    if (locationGlobal != null) updateMarker(locationGlobal);
}
```

Comment: locationchanged is only called when either the defined distance or defined time criteria is fulfilled.

Comment: inside on location changed get current location lat long and u can get current lat long.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://www.journaldev.com/13325/android-location-api-tracking-gps), it tracks location on map... **onLocationChanged(Location location)** method called when the **location has changed**.

Comment: I tried but still, I am not getting location value frequently. Actually, this code not calling onLocationChange method.